# Symfony 5 LDAP JumpCloud Authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication, ldap, cloud

I am just trying to configure LDAP authentication using JumpCloud service.
JumpCloud is public LDAP server with web adminisration. For connectiong to LDAP I am using built-in modul and following this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html

**It seems the system will connect succesly on to LDAP but cannot authenticate users.**

Output header:
[Output header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaKMW.png)

## Here are my settings:

**config/services.yaml**

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']

Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: ldap.jumpcloud.com
            port: 636
            encryption: ssl
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

**config/packages/security.yaml**

```
providers:
     my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: uid
            extra_fields: ['mail']
            filter: ({uid_key}={username})
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: false
        http_basic_ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'uid=LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME,ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'
            search_password: 'LDAP_ADMIN_PASS'
```

## Manual connection test:

```
$dn = "uid=LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME,ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com";
$password = "LDAP_ADMIN_PASS";

$ldap = Ldap::create('ext_ldap', ['connection_string' => 'ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com:636']);

$ldap->bind($dn, $password);

$query = $ldap->query('ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com', '(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)');
$results = $query->execute();
```

This code have returned valid output:

```
array (size=3)
0 => object(Symfony\Component\Ldap\Entry)[5504]
       private 'dn' => string 'uid=janakdom,ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com' (length=68)
       private 'attributes' => ..
1 => object(Symfony\Component\Ldap\Entry)[5093]
       private 'dn' => string 'uid=ldapservice,ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com' (length=71)
       private 'attributes' => ...
2 => object(Symfony\Component\Ldap\Entry)[4926]
       private 'dn' => string 'uid=test,ou=Users,o=MY_ORG_ID,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com' (length=64)
       private 'attributes' => ...
```

A absolutely don't know where the problem could be. I tried everything what occurred to me. I also use [oficial JumpCloud documentation](https://support.jumpcloud.com/support/s/article/using-jumpclouds-ldap-as-a-service1)

I would ask you for help.

Thank you very much 
DJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work for JumpCloud, in support for the last couple years, and in a technical editor capacity now. A couple of changes to your configuration may help:

1)  Under "providers > my_ldap > ldap:", there is no "search_dn", which will need to be the service LDAP Bind DN created in JumpCloud and appears to have been configured under "security > firewalls > main > http_basic_ldap:" per the screenshot above as 'uid=LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME,ou=users,o=,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'.

2) Under "security > firewalls > main > http_basic_ldap:", the "dn_string" is used to construct the FUll LDAP Bind DN of the user being authenticated.  Per the example in the documentation, this needs to be set with the proper syntax for value substitution as noted below.

'uid={username},ou=users,o=,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'

Hope this helps -- if not, I would definitely suggest opening a case with support@jumpcloud.com.

Brandon